# update/merge array values in React Redux store correctly without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

My initial state is like below and if new Book added or price is changed then new  updated array is coming from service whose result i need to merge in my initial state.

```
const initialState = {
  booksData: [
    {"Code":"BK01","price":"5"},
    {"code":"BK02","price":"30"},
    {"code":"BK03","price":"332"},
    {"code":"BK04","price":"123"}
  ] 
};
```

Updated array from server with few records updated/new

```
data: [
  {"Code":"BK01","price":"10"},
  {"code":"BK02","price":"25"},       
  {"code":"BK05","price":"100"}
]
```

updated state should become after merging updated array with old array.

```
booksData: [
  {"Code":"BK01","price":"10"},
  {"code":"BK02","price":"25"},
  {"code":"BK03","price":"332"},
  {"code":"BK04","price":"123"},
  {"code":"BK05","price":"100"}
]
```

Comment: Keep in mind you are not "merging" arrays, you are creating a brand new array. It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the two array and filter using 'Code' property

```
const initialState = {
    booksData: [
        { "Code": "BK01", "price": "5" },
        { "code": "BK02", "price": "30" },
        { "code": "BK03", "price": "332" },
        { "code": "BK04", "price": "123" }
    ]
};

const data =
[
    { "Code": "BK01", "price": "10" },
    { "code": "BK02", "price": "25" },
    { "code": "BK05", "price": "100" }
]


let newState = [...initialState.booksData, ...data];
newState = newState.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj['Code']).indexOf(obj['Code']) !== pos;
});
console.log(newState);
```

Answer (score 9):

I would filter out elements of the old data that are in the new data, and concat.

```
const oldBooks = booksData.filter(book => !newData.some(newBook => newBook.code === book.code));
return oldBooks.concat(newData);
```

Keep in mind you must NOT push values into the old array. In your reducer you MUST create new instances, here a new array. 'concat' does that.

Comment: Does this mutate state?

Comment: Array.filter also returns a new array. You can just push the newData. No need to use concat. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: immutability is a state of mind :) use it everywhere, all your code is gonna be easier to read/maintain

Answer (score 3):

You can first merge both the array together and then `reduce` it to remove duplicates like

```js
var booksData = [
   {"code":"BK01","price":"5"},
   {"code":"BK02","price":"30"},
   {"code":"BK03","price":"332"},
   {"code":"BK04","price":"123"}
   ] 

var newData = [
   {"code":"BK01","price":"10"},
   {"code":"BK02","price":"25"},       
   {"code":"BK05","price":"100"}
   ] 

const result = [...newData, ...booksData].reduce((res, data, index, arr) => {
  if (res.findIndex(book => book.code === data.code ) < 0) { 
      res.push(data);

  }  
  return res;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you can also write the condition like this: `if(!~res.findIndex(book => book.code === data.code ))`. just saying :)

Comment: @Sagivb.g, Thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer it this way, its easier to understand :)

Comment: if readability is your concern then i think [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is way more readable and easy to understand. :)

Comment: @Galupuf yup! i mixed it up with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). my bad :)  `if (!res.some(book => book.code === data.code ))`

Answer (score 0):

### Collection of Objects

Filter a merged array to pick only non-existent items by iterating every item in the merged array which its index is before the current index of the "parent" *filter* iterator

```js
const mergedUnique = [
    ...[{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}], 
    ...[{id:1}, {id:4}, {id:2}]
  ]
  .filter((item, idx, arr) => 
    !arr.some(({id}, subIdx) => subIdx < idx && id == item.id) 
  )

console.log( mergedUnique )
```

### Basic technique for "simple" arrays

Merge some arrays and filter them to pick only non-existent items by checking if the same item exists anywhere **before** the current item's index in the merged array.

`lastIndexOf` is used to check *backwards*, if the current value exists *already*, which contributes to keeping the order of the merged array in a certain way which might be desirable, which can only be achieved by checking *backward* and not *forward*.

Skip checking the first item - is obviously *not* a duplicate.

```js
const mergedUniqe = [...[1,2,3], ...[1,3,4,5,2]] // [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
  .filter((item, idx, arr) => 
    !~arr.lastIndexOf(item, idx-1) || !idx
  )
    
console.log( mergedUniqe )
```